# Checkout SVN repository from outside local network using different port than the standard 3690

Tags: svn

I have an Ubuntu server on my company's local network running a Subversion server. I can access this repository easily from inside the network using svn://localip/repos-name

I'm trying to set this up so that members of the team can access the Subversion server from home. We have a static IP address. Unfortunately we aren't the only team working in this company and the other team already has Subversion running on their server. Since they set it up first they have taken the 3690 port and forwarded it to their server.

We now have to access our Subversion server using a different port (that is, forward say port 19333 to point to our Subversion server on port 3690).

However I can't seem to find anywhere how to access our Subversion server which is using our different port.

I've tried `svn://staticip:19333/repo-name`, but this gives an error saying no repositories available.

We use [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) to access repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to diagnose this kind of connection problem is to use `telnet`:

```
telnet staticIPaddress 19333
```

If you get a connection and the Subversion server gives you a header (it has some parentheses, but I don't recall precisely what it looks like) then you've got a good connection and the problem likely lies with TortoiseSVN and its syntax for using alternate ports (I think that part is correct though). However, if you can't make this connection then you will need to investigate your port forwarding setup.